# Algorithm Lists with python

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I am trying to find an algorithm to solve the following problem with python.

`Given a list of integers, check if after dropping two elements of the list, is it possible to divide the list in 3 where the sum of the consecutive numbers are equals.`

For example:
A = [1, 3, **4**, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, **2**] should return **TRUE** because we would drop the elements in bold the list can be slit in **[1, 3], [2, 2], [2, 1, 1]** where all sum 4

B = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] should return **FALSE**

C = [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, **1034**, 5, **9900**, 1, 2] should also return **FALSE** because eventhough after droping the numbers in bold you can sum have the numbers to sum 5 (1,1,3), (5), (1, 1, 1, 2) the list should be sorted first and that's not allowed.

I have come with a solution that seems to work but it is very, very bad and not sure if always work, and the complexity is too high when should be **O(n)**
I don't know how to iterate removing 2 numbers from a list without having a complexity of **O(n^2)**

Thanks

Comment: I'd be amazed if this is possible in O(n). In the worst case you have to check the whole list (minus 2 items) for every pair of numbers in the list.

Comment: may be you should post this question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sounds like a variation of bin-packing...

Comment: this will help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-subarrays-sum-exactly-equal-k/

Comment: Thanks @deadshot but the thing is that you don't know the sum, that would make it easier.

Comment: what do you meany by you don't know the sum

Comment: In the function of the post that you sent, the sum is entered as a parameter. Anyway, the thing I find dificult here is droping 2 items of the list to check the condition with a complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to solve this problem in `O(n)` (given that the integers are positive) where `n` is the size of your array `A`.

It can be surprising since the problem reminds of the bin packing, or subset sum problems, but the fact that we look for consecutive sum in the array makes the task much easier.

Here is a python code doing it:

```
def find_couple_list_sum(int_list):
    n = len(int_list)
    left_sum = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(1, n):
        left_sum[i] = left_sum[i-1] + int_list[i-1]

    right_sum = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    for j in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        right_sum[j] = right_sum[j+1] + int_list[j+1]

    total_sum = sum(int_list)
    print(left_sum)
    print(right_sum)
    print(total_sum)
    i, j = 0, n-1
    while True:
        print(i, j)
        mid_sum = total_sum - left_sum[i] - right_sum[j] - int_list[i] - int_list[j]
        if left_sum[i] == right_sum[j] and left_sum[i] == mid_sum:
            return i, j
        elif i == j:
            return None, None
        elif left_sum[i] < right_sum[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j -= 1


int_list = [1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
print(find_couple_list_sum(int_list))
```

The whole thing runs indeed in `O(n)`.

Comment: Aren't you always dividing at the two dropped elements?

Comment: Yes I am. Indeed that is not exactly what the OP asked for, with the OP's version of the problem I do not see how one can solve the problem in O(n).

Comment: Hello @m.raynal, I don't fully understand the code, is it returning the index of the elements that would be dropped?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does